# What does a limit sign with a line either top or bottom mean?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, notation, limsup-and-liminf

Can someone please explain what the symbols $\varliminf$ and $\varlimsup$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates "limit superior"/"limit inferior" (aka liminf and limsup), see [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limes_superior_und_Limes_inferior).